# Cylindrical coordinates: Paradox?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

Let's say the vector field $\vec A_1 = \begin{pmatrix} r\\ 0 \\ z\end{pmatrix}$ in cylindrical coordinates is given and I want to calculate $\vec A_1 \cdot \vec e_r$, where $\vec e_r = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi) \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

1) $ \begin{pmatrix} r \\ 0 \\ z\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi) \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = r \cos(\phi)  $

2)  $\vec A_1 = \begin{pmatrix} r\\ 0 \\ z\end{pmatrix} = r \cdot\vec e_r + z \cdot \vec e_z$
thus $\vec A_1 \cdot \vec e_r = r \cdot\vec e_r \cdot \vec e_r + z \cdot \vec e_r \cdot \vec e_z= r$

Which one is right and where is the mistake?

Comment: In equation 1), the first vector is in cylindrical coordinates and the second vector is in cartesian $(x,y,z)$ coordinates, so the dot product can’t be calculated the way you’re doing it.

Comment: so the second one is correct?

Comment: Yes. And if you write $(r,0,z)$ in cartesian coordinates as $(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi,z)$, you can take the dot product as you tried to in equation 1) and you’ll get $r(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi)=r$.